# How to move text element in the footer?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I have added two columns within the container but would like the .company and .copyright text at the bottom left of the footer in the column. The Follow Us heading should be on the right with the .justify-text underneath it followed by social media elements. Thanks!

```css
.footer {
  background-color: $pink;
  padding-top: 20px;
  text-align: left;
  color: $white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="footer">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-between">
      <div class="col-sm-7">
        <h5>Programme</h5>
        <p class="company">This is text.</p>
        <p class="copyright">© 2023 Blah Blah Blah</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <h5>Follow Us</h5>
        <p class="justify-text">Join our socials and stay tuned.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So you want the `.copyright` centered between each column?

Comment: @Kameron both the .copyright and .company should be at the bottom of the left column and the Programme heading at the top. The Follow us heading should be centered on the right with the .justify-text in the middle followed by social media elements underneath it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following. The description wasn't clear to me, so let me know if you want anything changed.

```css
.footer {
  background-color: $pink;
  padding-top: 20px;
  text-align: left;
  color: $white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="footer">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-between">
      <div class="col-sm-7">
        <h5>Programme</h5>
        <p class="company pt-5">This is text.</p>
        <p class="copyright">© 2023 Blah Blah Blah</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
        <h5>Follow Us</h5>
        <p class="justify-text pt-5">Join our socials and stay tuned.</p>
        <ul class="list-unstyled p-0 d-flex justify-content-around">
          <li>Icon 1</li>
          <li>Icon 2</li>
          <li>Icon 3</li>
          <li>Icon 4</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for! I would have shared a draft image but not enough points unfortunately but got it. Thank you